# Force Textfield to left to right in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, localization, uitextfield, text-alignment

I'm working with an application that has English and Arabic localizations. I need a Textfield to be in left to right text alignment in Arabic as well as English. But I'm not able to force the semantic from left to right.
I've written the following code in viewDidLoad.

```
self.textField.textAlignment = .left
self.textField.semanticContentAttribute = UISemanticContentAttribute.forceLeftToRight
```

I've also tried putting the textField in a UIView and forcing the views semantic to the left to right. But still is not doesn't work.

```
self.textAreaView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
```

Let me know if somebody has forced the text field from left to right in the case of RTL language. Any links are also appreciated.

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I'm not able to find any solutions for this and had to change the app Flow. Still, if somebody is able to find any solution it will be very Helpful.

Comment: How do you add constraints for the textField? Normally if you add leading / trailing it depends on language while right / left  forces it to what you wish for.

Comment: I've added left and right constraints to superview as textfield has borders and it is in the centre.

Comment: Use .natural which will do this automatically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UItextView arabic text aligned to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869923/uitextview-arabic-text-aligned-to-right)